# Convert elses into switch with boolean return value

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am trying to convert this simple set of else statement into a more easily readable switch;

```
$parts_arr = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

if (in_array('dev', $parts_arr)) {
    DEFINE('APP_ENV', "dev");
} else if (in_array('staging', $parts_arr)) {
    DEFINE('APP_ENV', "staging");
} else if (in_array('local', $parts_arr)) {
    DEFINE('APP_ENV', "local");
} else {
    DEFINE('APP_ENV', "live");
}
```

However I have completely drawn a blank. I can't use a foreach loop and use the string as the case as `APP_ENV` cannot be redefined.

Comment: You're first if and elseif makes completely no sense!

Comment: You can't really turn this into a switch statement, at least not in any clean way. It's quite readable anyway.

Comment: Ok, what if I have `SERVER_NAME` as `staging.local.dev` ?

Comment: @AlmaDo Then I guess this question is the least of your problems

Answer (score 1):

You may only check the whole server name.

```
switch($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
    case 'mysite.com':
    case 'www.mysite.com':
      DEFINE('APP_ENV', "live");
      break;
    case 'dev.mysite.com':
      DEFINE('APP_ENV', "dev");
      break;
    case 'staging.mysite.com':
      DEFINE('APP_ENV', "staging");
      break;
    case 'mylocalhost.local':
      DEFINE('APP_ENV', "local");
      break;
    default:
      exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn it into switch-case structure unless you're doing string comparaison.

Maybe something like this :

```
$str = array_pop(explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']));

switch($str)
{
   case 'dev' :
      DEFINE('APP_ENV', "dev");
   break;
   // en so on
}
```

Sunil Pachlangia's solution won't work because he is comparing an array and a string

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$parts_arr = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
switch (true) {
    case in_array('dev', $parts_arr):
        DEFINE('APP_ENV', "dev");
        break;
    case in_array('staging', $parts_arr):
        DEFINE('APP_ENV', "staging");
        break;
    case in_array('local', $parts_arr):
        DEFINE('APP_ENV', "local");
        break;
    default:
        DEFINE('APP_ENV', "live");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd tend to shy away from splitting strings and analysing array elements, as @Almo-Do commented Be specific in some kind of config file.

```
$environments = array(
  'localhost' = > 'local'
, 'staging.mysite.com' > 'staging'
// etc - see? now you can comment some out
//, 'mysite.com' => 'live'
);
```

Then simply

```
define ('APP_ENV', $environments[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]);
```

Or even be a bit more defensive prior to that, something like :

```
if (!array_key_exists($environments[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) die('suitable msg');
```